# Confused about the element number is -1 for array

Tags: c++

I'm reading a code from here:
https://github.com/chenshuo/muduo/blob/master/muduo/base/Date.cc

But I'm confused about these two lines:

```
char require_32_bit_integer_at_least[sizeof(int) >= sizeof(int32_t) ? 1 : -1];
```

and

```
(void) require_32_bit_integer_at_least; // no warning please
```

What's the purpose of them?

```
char require_32_bit_integer_at_least[sizeof(int) >= sizeof(int32_t) ? 1 : -1];

int getJulianDayNumber(int year, int month, int day)
{
  (void) require_32_bit_integer_at_least; // no warning please
  int a = (14 - month) / 12;
  int y = year + 4800 - a;
  int m = month + 12 * a - 3;
  return day + (153*m + 2) / 5 + y*365 + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 - 32045;
}
```

Comment: Maybe they are trying to generate a compilation error for platforms where `int` is less than 32 bits.

Comment: @barakmanos ok, maybe, any other good solution?

Comment: With no other information provided, this code makes very little sense IMO. It is obvious that we need 32-bit integers here, due to the usage of `y*365` and `32045` (i.e., a reasonable chance for exceeding 16 bits during the calculation). But that's about as far as I can find any good explanation for this unusual syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code requires that an `int` is at least 32 bit wide.
If that is not the case and `sizeof(int)` is less than 32 bit you would get an error like:

```
error: size of array 'require_32_bit_integer_at_least' is negative
```

The line

```
(void) require_32_bit_integer_at_least; // no warning please
```

seems to be to avoid the "unused variable" warning. However, as the array is global and non-static the compiler would not generate a warning anyhow.
Knowing that a global non-static variable is really unused would require checking all translation units (source files) in the entire project.

---

As proposed by @MartinBonner, to make it clearer and easier to use, we could define a "static assert" macro:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(EXPR, MSG) typedef char static_assertion_##MSG[(EXPR) ? 1 : -1]
```

and use it as follows:

```
STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(int) >= sizeof(int32_t), int_is_less_than_32_bit);    

const bool foo = true;
STATIC_ASSERT(foo, foo_is_not_true);
```

Comment: This is the classic "static assert" mechanism.  Personally I'd have written it as `typedef struct { require_32_bit_integer_at_least[sizeof(int) >= sizeof(int32_t) ? 1 : -1] require_32_bit_integer_at_least} ;` and wrapped it in a #define.

Comment: That's what I thought about the `(void)` declaration. The only problem is, that the compiler cannot optimize away a **non-static global variable**, even if it is unused in this source file, because it is possibly used in some other source file. Perhaps the linker can do that, but as far as I know, linkers don't do that.

Comment: **−1** "However, as the array is not defined as static the compiler would not generate a warning anyhow." is nonsense and manifestly untrue.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf My understanding is that the compiler does not generate "unused variable" warnings for non-static global variables. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The code is not prettified (see the link). The array declaration is global, not inside the function. The cast to (void) does not make sense to me either, that's what I was trying say with "However, ...".

Answer (score 1):

`char require_32_bit_integer_at_least[sizeof(int) >= sizeof(int32_t) ? 1 : -1];` is declaring an array before any actual code inside your methods is run.  If the size of an int is less than 32 bit (e.g. a compiler where an int is 24 or 16 bits), then it will attempt to create an array of size -1, which is not allowed and will cause an error meaning that the code will not run.

The line `(void) require_32_bit_integer_at_least; // no warning please` stops the compiler from complaining about an unused array.

Comment: Why does it stop it being optimized away?  How would a C++ program tell if it had been optimized away or not?  (And if the answer is "it can't", then the compiler can optimize it.)

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 and later just use standard **`static_assert`**.

You're looking at one particular C++03 technique to implement a static (that is, compile time) assertion.

An alternative technique used a `typedef` of a type nested in a class template, which did not have such a nested type for `false` template argument. This had an advantage in that a `typedef` can occur just about anywhere, and can be repeated with identical definition (unless the compiler is non-conforming, as one was at the time). The technique could be further elaborated to provide a decent informative error message, which Andrei Alexandrescu explored in his now classic “Modern C++ Design” book.

---

So how does

```
char require_32_bit_integer_at_least[sizeof(int) >= sizeof(int32_t) ? 1 : -1];
```

… work as a static assertion?

Well if the array size is `-1` then the code is ill-formed.

It would also be ill-formed with array size `0`, but some compilers would erroneously accept that; hence the conditional operator (or in some cases an arithmetic expression) instead of a simple boolean.

---

With the assert in a local scope, the following

```
(void) require_32_bit_integer_at_least; // no warning please
```

… would do exactly what the comment explains: there it suppresses a possible warning about the variable not being used.

However, in the original code the assert is at namespace scope and the cast to `void` inside a function. That's meaningless for standard C++. One possible reason could be that a specific compiler optimized away the assertion variable, and erroneously accepted code where that assertion did  not hold, and that the local use of the variable prevented that behavior, with the comment then completely misleading.